# Android app crashes on shouldInterceptRequest

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to use shouldInterceptRequest to close my webview when i want to load certain URL but the app crashes when i do so.

For checking url against what is coming from web i use webview.getURL() method. I am running this method on UI thread to get the URL.

Please find my code below

```
 public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(final WebView view, String url) {

        WebActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                CloseURL = webView.getUrl();

            }
        });

        if (CloseURL.contains("dummyurl") &&BackPressed) {
            BackPressed=false;
            CloseURL="";

            WebActivity.this.finish();

        }
        return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);

    }
```

Comment: and the stacktrace is?

Comment: secondly why is the uithread used here I guess its already in uithread

Comment: In stacktrace i get a warning like  :07-28 19:34:05.450: W/webview_proxy(13113): java.lang.Throwable: Warning: A WebView method was called on thread 'WebViewCoreThread'. All WebView methods must be called on the UI thread. Future versions of WebView may not support use on other threads.

Answer (score 1):

When you do this,

```
    WebActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            CloseURL = webView.getUrl();

        }
    });
```

it queues that code to run later. Then you go on to use `CloseUrl` immediately after this. If you are expecting `CloseUrl` to be assigned when you use it here,

```
    if (CloseURL.contains("dummyurl") &&BackPressed) {
```

you are wrong, it won't have been assigned yet. The code that assigns it won't have run yet.

You should move the code that depends on `CloseUrl` into your `Runnable.run()`.

public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(final WebView view, String url) {

```
    WebActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            CloseURL = webView.getUrl();
            if (CloseURL.contains("dummyurl") &&BackPressed) {
                BackPressed=false;
                CloseURL="";

                WebActivity.this.finish();

            }
        }
    });

    return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
}
```

Comment: Hi Jeffrey, thanks for the information. Currently i am using android 4.3 and app is crashing here. this is happening because geturl() runs on UI thread and code within shouldInterceptRequest() runs on another thread. In android 4.3 we are not allowed to call webview methods like geturl() on another thread so app crashes. Please let me know if we have any workaround for this.

Comment: As I mentioned, move the code that uses CloseURL into the `run()` method. See update.